# How to effectively implement 1 to many relationship?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, .net-4.8

I have an EF model to is connected 1 to 1 for many tables but I am having trouble connecting a 1 to many table. Currently using EF6 on .Net 4.8. The error I am recieving is "Multiplicity is not valid in Role '' in relationship 'Login_Users'. Because the Dependent Role refers to the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '1'"

The main table is
**Users**

```
public partial class Users
{
    public Users()
    {
        this.Login = new HashSet<Login>();
        this.Phone = new HashSet<Phone>();
    }
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public int LastFourSSN { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> AddressId { get; set; }


    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Login> Login { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Phone> Phone { get; set; }
}
```

**One to one tables**

```
public partial class Login
{
    public Login()
    {
        this.Login_Track = new HashSet<Login_Track>();
        this.Policy = new HashSet<Policy>();
    }

    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Key, ForeignKey("Users")]
    public Nullable<int> UserId { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastLoginDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Users Users { get; set; }
}
```

**Address**

```
public partial class Address
{
    public Address()
    {
        this.Users = new HashSet<Users>();
    }
    [Key, ForeignKey("Users")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Users> Users { get; set; }
}
```

**1 to many table**

```
public partial class Phone
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Users")]
    public Nullable<int> UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual Users Users { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: "*I have an EF model to is connected 1 to 1 for many tables*" - this is the problem to begin with. Why can't person have many addresses? Make it 1-to-many. Take Amazon. You can have many addresses where you ship stuff. 1-to-1 has serious implications, Not only in EF but for DB as well

Comment: @T.S. any guidance to implementing this with what I presented?

Comment: No. One time I had to setup EF for the existing DB that was constructed in somewhat erratic way. I've spend days to setup EF to work correctly. I don't have time for doing this here. But I can say this - make good design of your DB and you will not have problems you running into